# HowTo on default page animation

Tags: animation, windows-phone-7

Can someone give an example on how to animation page navigation in WP7?

I actually only just want to use the flip animation used in most default installed application i.e. the Settings application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can be something of use?

[Page Transition Animations and Windows Phone 7](http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2010/11/09/Page-Transition-Animations-and-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)